# Почему NetBeans не позволяет создать пакет?

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Сам не позволяет создать пакет META-INF, а при его создании вручную, не видит. Думаю, из-за этого у меня не получается привязать Bean к xhtml.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И еще у меня есть xhtml файл, который я открываю браузере. Работает все, кроме бинов. Отсюда я делаю вывод, что что-то случатся с злополучным бином, ибо браузер так и выводит `{#exampleBean.text}`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Кодировка{#exampleBean.text}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Текст на русском языке в стандартной кодировке Windows.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что дефис является невалидным символом в названии класса, а пакет является его частью. Вам нужно создать не пакет, а ресурсную директорию `META-INF`. Судя по всему Netbeans разделяет код и ресурсы, как это делает Maven, то есть ресурсы лежат в директории проекта, отличной от директории в которой лежит код. Проверьте это! Директорию `META-INF` вам нужно создать там, где лежат ресурсы.

Comment: как я должен это сделать, если у меня нет такой директории, как ресурсы?

Comment: Судя по добавленной вами картинке у вас есть `Другие исходные файлы`, где и лежат ваши ресурсы. Попробуйте созать `META-INF` сразу под `Другие исходные файлы`.

Comment: вот, уже раньше создавал

Comment: Тут еще? Не спите?)

Comment: Помогите.......